# Dandelion Datatables + Thymeleaf Cannot specify custom loading message

Tags: datatable, dandelion

I'm trying to specify a custom processing message while Datatables is making an ajax call, however Dandelion Datatables provides no direct dt:config (or whatever) option  to set it. I've tried to follow the documentation [here](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/configuration/configuration-overloading.html) and [here](http://dandelion.github.io/datatables/features/i18n/internationalization.html) by specifying a custom configuration property like so:

```
<div dt:confType="property" dt:name="global.i18n.msg.processing" dt:value="My custom message..."></div>
```

...with no success. What am I doing wrong, or are the properties specified in the documentation not "configuration properties"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the group name from the configuration option, and it should work:

```
<div dt:confType="property" dt:name="i18n.msg.processing" dt:value="My custom message..."></div>
```

Comment: Tested this in 0.10.1, it works, but as soon as I had upgraded to Dandelion Datatables 1.0.1 or 1.1.0, Thymeleaf complained that "property" is not a valid confType.

Comment: Yes, the right value is now "option". I've just noticed that the docs hasn't been updated accordingly. Thanks!